# Ordering items in database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm searching for an efficient way to add order the inserted item in a table in a database.

I'm thinking of two ways to strategies to achieve it.

**First strategy:**

to add order column in the table, and maintain its consistency with every Create, Update, and Delete (its very costly method) especially when I need to change the order, I need to change all elements after the updated element.

```
item order
 1     2
 2     1
 3     4
 4     3
```

**Second strategy:**

to make a meta_data table for all metadata and save the order and id of the product.
for example:

**'products' => [{id:1, order:2}, {id:2:order:1},......]**

I can replace the metadata list with each modification, but it is also a costly method when selecting data from a table.

Are there any more efficient way.

Comment: Use trigger or procedure

Comment: I would use something like the first strategy. The second strategy doesn't feel like a strategy at all to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are insistent on ordering correctly after every edit, create a view like so:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewerData AS 
    SELECT * FROM Products
    ORDER BY Id
```

Then use the view as your back end table, whilst you are still able to update the actual table - by using the view instead of the table, it will automatically reorder every time you requery.

Comment: i would add in `ALGORITHM = MERGE` Views with algoritme merge tends to optimize better..The MySQL optimizer rewrites the query `SELECT * FROM ViewerData` to `SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY id` see the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html